# Quarkus Reactive throws "`hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` was enabled."

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, quarkus-panache, quarkus-reactive

I've migrated my application to Quarkus Reactive and I'm seeing this log message whenever I persist an entity with Hibernate Reactive Panache

> 2022-01-30 17:04:04,864 DEBUG
> [org.hib.res.jdb.int.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl]
> (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5)
> `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` was enabled.  This
> setting should only be enabled when you are certain that the
> Connections given to Hibernate by the ConnectionProvider have
> auto-commit disabled.  Enabling this setting when the Connections do
> not have auto-commit disabled will lead to Hibernate executing SQL
> operations outside of any JDBC/SQL transaction.

Why am I seeing this and what implications does it have?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the message as it's a "DEBUG" level information, and it doesn't apply to Quarkus: all JDBC connections in Quarkus are handled by Agroal, which guarantees autocommit was already disabled.

It's a bit concerning you claim you're using Hibernate Reactive Panache though: Hibernate Reactive does not use JDBC and isn't using this `LogicalConnectionManagedImpl`, so it would seem you're mixing JDBC and Reactive database access, which is not currently supported.